# What is the proper syntax for grouping conditions in a if-statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I'm having trouble fully understanding the syntax of if-statement in python. Is it possible to group up conditions as demonstrated below?

`if my_age and neighborhood_age > 20:`

Will python understand the above code **exactly** as:
`if my_age> 20 and neighborhood_age > 20:` ?

Provided it does understand exactly the same thing, how can I group conditions? e.g.:

Suppose I have three conditions:

`my_age and neighborhood_age > 20
father_age < 60
cousin_age < my age`

What is the correct way to write the if-statement?
`if (my_age and neighborhood_age > 20) and (father_age < 60) and (cousin_age < my age):` ?

And what happens if I start mixing 'and' and 'or' operators? What is the best way to write the following code:

`if ((my_age and neighborhood_age > 20) and (father_age < 60) and (cousin_age < my age)) or girlfriend_age > 18:`

Comment: you have essentially all the syntax figured out, why don't you try running it and see what happens? (and to address the first portion, don't write conditions like `if my_age and neighborhood_age > 20`, your 2nd code would be the way to write it. `if my_age> 20 and neighborhood_age > 20` Other than that however, its all spot on. just try it out.

Comment: The second example works well if I have a few variables to match a condition, but what should I do if I want to compare dozens of variables to a value?

Comment: python provides quite a few tools to deal with multiple conditions. take a look at `any`, `all` and membership tests `in` that can make setting up the more complex conditions trivial. All require setting up some kind of list first, and then the check becomes easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will python understand the above code exactly as: if my_age> 20 and neighborhood_age > 20: ?

No, it will not. Python will interpret it as this:

```
if (my_age) and (neighborhood_age > 20)
```

If you want to compare two values against a third, you must do it like so:

```
if (my_age > 20 and neighborhood_age > 20): ...
```

Or, with grouping for absolute clarity:

```
if ((my_age > 20) and (neighborhood_age > 20)): ...
```

If you have many values to compare, you can use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(age > 20 for age in (my_age, neighborhood_age)): ...
```

As for your last example, I would probably write it like this, using multiple lines and parenthesis to remove ambiguity:

```
if ((my_age > 20 and neighborhood_age > 20) and 
    (father_age < 60) and 
    (cousin_age < my age)
) or (girlfriend_age > 18):
    ...
```

In almost all but the simplest of cases, you should use parenthesis to make your intention absolutely clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write each condition on it's own. The `and` keyword is the same thing that putting a `if` statement inside a `if` statement.
For example :

```
if my_age >= 20 and neighborhood_age >= 20:
    # Do something
```

Is the same thing that

```
if my_age >= 20:
    if neighborhood_age >= 20:
         # Do something
```

To mix `and` and `or` the cleaner way is to use well parentheses and end line.